# Ubuntu with Nginx and Apache - Issues with Reaching Nginx Landing Page

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, configuration

I have an Ubuntu Server with both apache2 and nginx installed (Apache2 was installed by the system admin, and I installed nginx).

I cannot reach the default port that nginx is set to, it redirects me to apache's default page. I've tried changing the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file to:

```
server {
        listen 81 default_server;
        listen [::]:81 default_server;
}
```

I restarted/reloaded the nginx service after making the changes but still land on the apache2 page. Is there something else that I need to edit in order to be able to access nginx? Thank you.

Comment: When you go to `hostname:81` you get Apache answering?

Comment: What happens if you try to stop the Apache2 service with "service apache2 stop"?

Comment: @OlafKock Yes, I get Apache answering.

Comment: whoops - I thought something else than I typed: On 81, you should get nginx answering, while (I assume) on 80, Apache httpd would answer. Unless it's configured differently or unless nginx is redirecting you (e.g. to https - or http - without port on the same host)